# how to remove year from column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this solution in python that I am trying to replicate in SQL Server.

movies_df['title']

| title |
| --- |
| Toy Story (1995) |
| The 2000 Year Old Man (1975) |
| The With (2) Sant (1999) |

I run this code and it gets rid of the year

movies_df['title'] = movies_df.title.str.replace('((\d\d\d\d))', '')

Output:

| title |
| --- |
| Toy Story |
| The 2000 Year Old Man |
| The With (2) Sant |

I have a table called movies in SQL. I want to do get the same output in SQL

select movie_title from movies

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is the Year **always** at the end of the string?

Comment: Yes year is always at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have found out, SQL Server has no pattern replacement functionality. You'll need to use pattern matching, and then remove that many characters. I assume the value is always at the end, and always preceded by a space:

```sql
SELECT V.Title,
       STUFF(V.title,PATINDEX('% ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])',V.Title),7,'')
FROM (VALUES('Toy Story (1995)'),
            ('The 2000 Year Old Man (1975)'),
            ('The With (2) Sant (1999)'))V(title)
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem. Do you know how I can also get just the year without the brackets as a separate column? I want to get the title without the year and extract the year in a separate column

Comment: Honestly, do that in Python, and then store the data in a normalised format (with the title and year in separate columns) to start with. SQL Server is far from the best at string manipulation.

Comment: Try `substring()` rather than `stuff()`. Try playing around with the tools.